# Google Chrome STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION Error

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, access-violation

Many people have been getting this issue on accessing web pages.

And the only solution is to update google chrome and clear all cache and other advanced stuff.

But I'm a web developer and I cant wait for all my customers to update their browser.

So, should be an easier solution, right?

I believe we found one and will post it / share it bellow, but I'm gonna let this open so we can discuss and add new information on this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a web developer and I cant wait for all my customers to update Google Chrome, so..
We have been debugging this issue and founded a solution!

Seem to be a CSS simple-to-fix problem.
Seems that in some version of Chromes update's they have forbidden some html TAGs to have BEFORE and AFTER contents. One of this tags is Fieldset. Our team didnt find any other, but removing a fieldset:before{ content: ''; ... } solves the problem immeadiatly!

If you found any others TAGS please post it here. If you having the same problem, search your CSS code for :before and :after statements, should be easy to fix.

Thank you, bye.

~ Rodrigo - Elo Ideias Dev Team